# Cannot INSERT INTO VALUES() in SQL Fiddle

Tags: sql-server, sqlfiddle

*Fixed, no idea why but now it works*

No idea why, but I cannot insert anything into SQL Fiddle. I just did the same thing in SSMS and it works.

I built the schema on left screen:

```
CREATE TABLE day1 (
  A int,
  B int,
  C int
);
```

And then INSERT data on right screen:

```
INSERT INTO day1 (A, B, C)
VALUES (1, 4, 9);
```

And then SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM day1
```

It shows nothing, 0 record count. I'm scratching my head to understand where the problem is.

Comment: Can't replicate your issue  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=99fda2b31a215adf1b4fcad29b65b0c2

Comment: Thanks, this is weird. I tried multiple times both on remote PC and local PC, neither worked.

Comment: It is working fine on SQLFiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0e263/1/0 can you provide a link

Comment: Hi guys, now it works, I have no idea why...

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you were missing `;` after `INSERT INTO`:

**[SQL Fiddle Demo - no ouput](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0e263/4/0)**

[image]

It is a good practice to finish each statement with semicolon:

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0e263/3/1)**

Comment: No I'm actually finishing with `;`
Somehow I'm having the same problem again.

Comment: If possible can you please check this fiddle? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f37aa/2
You can see that I have `;` but the `SELECT` returns 0 rows.

Comment: btw it works now. Seems I have to build schema at least 3-4 times for it to work. This is a bit frustrating but at least I know a solution. Basically everytime I run a new SQL script I have to rebuild the schema, otherwise I get 0 output.